# Model Y~X using longitudinal data when X is measured less often than Y

Tags: r, time-series, repeated-measures, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I have the following data/setting:

- N persons assessed over time: different number of assessments;
  assessments at different time points
- Variable Y: measured ~50 times (3 times per day)
- Variable X: measured at 5 time points

It is possible to model Y ~ X? I was thinking in using mixed models and account for the two levels (assessments nested in individuals) but I don't know how to do it without losing information (as would happen if I use just 5 measures of Y).

In practice, I'm looking for two time series (for each individual) and I want to know if X affects the dynamic of Y over time.

Comment: You can always use the five x values with the corresponding five y values. Is interpolation of x values a reasonable option?

Comment: @Roland, interpolation wouldn't be an option; use just 5 values of Y is possible but it means losing information. In practice, I'm looking for two time series (for each individual) and I want to know if X affects the dynamic of Y. I will edit my post to clarify these points. Thank you